# Unable to call function in java

Tags: java

When I try to call the lyrics function in this code, "invalid method declaration; return type required" occurs.
I'm learning java and very very new to it. I'm confused how to define the function and call the function so that code may run.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public void lyrics() {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }
    lyrics();
}
```

Comment: I'm learning from udacity. Their video does not use "static". What's the catch? https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud282/lessons/8192650550/concepts/a68c5c96-b98b-4989-8ca4-da90dbfd3d85

Comment: move the `lyrics()` call to `main()`, add `static` between `void` and `lyrics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're learning Java, you must remember that the only way to call a non-static method from a static method is to have an instance of the class containing the non-static method.

Or you can simply make your function static. Also, you need to call the function inside the main block.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        lyrics();
    }
    public static void lyrics() 
    {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Don't forget about initialization blocks. That's the one alternative. Not that they should necessarily be used everywhere. But it helps to know how `private int myField = 0;` gets set to zero.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to mention it since I hardly use them myself! Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: I'm learning from udacity. Why the teacher is not using it refer to 4 minute video: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud282/lessons/8192650550/concepts/a68c5c96-b98b-4989-8ca4-da90dbfd3d85

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one can't just invoke a method randomly in the body of the code. However, there is something called an *initialization block* (this gets run in the body of the constructors of the object). I think an example might clarify. Like,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(); // <-- instantiate an instance of Main
    }
    public void lyrics() {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }
    { // <-- this is an initialization block
        lyrics();
    }
}
```

The above uses the default constructor, we can add an explicit one. Like,

```
public Main() {
    super();
    System.out.println("In Main constructor");
}
```

Note how the output changes.

They can *also* be `static` (and run when the class is first referenced). Like,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public static void lyrics() {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }
    static {
        lyrics();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nearly correct. Your `lyrics()` method must be static if you want to call it inside main method because `main` method is static. Non static members cannot be accessed from static method (without creating an instance to invoke it).

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lyrics();
    }
    public static void lyrics() {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }

}
```

You can invoke non-static methods from static method by creating an instance of the class containing non-static method inside your main method as mentioned in comments by Elliott Frisch.

```java
new Main().lyrics();
```

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion, the method should be static.

Comment: Directly no! Unless you have an instance of the class containing non-static member. By definition, static methods work on Class level.

Comment: @PiyushPatel , your answer is partially correct when you write the statement like *Java has static keyword which only allows static methods to be called.* Please correct the statement and you are good to go.

Comment: @VishwaRatna I got what you mean. It confuses.

Comment: *Non static members cannot be accessed from static method* (without creating an instance to invoke it) - you need that parenthetical, because otherwise you are implying the patterns `Multiton` and `Singleton` are impossible to implement. Various creational patterns also take advantage of creating instances from a `static` context.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, your comment explains the gist about `Singleton` and `Multiton` design pattern.

Comment: @VishwaRatna `Factory`, `Flyweight`, `Prototype` and `Builder` design patterns too (just not the rationales - or implementation specifics).

Answer (score 0):

The method should be declared as static and function call should be within main method. The correct code should look like as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        lyrics();
    }
    public static void lyrics() 
    {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the call to `lyrics()` into the `main` method where code is actually executed.  Where you have it now, the compiler is expecting a new method defination.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // execution begins here.
        new Main().lyrics();
    }
    public void lyrics() {
        System.out.println("some lyrics here");
    }
}
```

EDIT: created new class `Main` class to avoid errors.

Comment: This will error as you are trying to call non-static method from static area